# Recyclerview is not updating?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm working on a chat app. In this app I want to sort contact lists with latest message timestamp.

```
     adapter = new ContactListAdapter(ob1, getActivity(), fusername);

            if (!adapted) {
                chatLists.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapted = true;
            }else {
                adapter.updateList(ob1, getActivity(), fusername);

            }
```

Here setAdapter works fine and updating the complete recyclerview with setAdapter works fine too. But it reloads the complete view with all data like image and user message. So I just want to refresh the index without loading all data again.

On the above code. adapted is a boolean value. It's initial value is false. And after setting the adapter initial value changes to true.  Then to update the adapter I call updateList function.

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactListAdapter.viewHolder>{
    com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot d;
    Context c;
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    String username;
    ArrayList<ChatroomLists> ob1 = new ArrayList<ChatroomLists>();


public ContactListAdapter(ArrayList<ChatroomLists> ob1, Context c, String fusername) {
    this.c = c;
    this.username = fusername;
    this.ob1.addAll(ob1);

}
public void updateList(ArrayList<ChatroomLists> ob1, Context c, String fusername) {
    this.ob1.clear();
    this.ob1.addAll(ob1);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();


}


    public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CircleImageView user_img;
        ImageView message_stats;
        TextView user_name;
        TextView user_message;
        TextView timestamp;
        CircleImageView unreadbadge;

        public viewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            user_img = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById (R.id.user_img_list);
            user_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById (R.id.contact_name);
            user_message = (TextView) itemView.findViewById (R.id.user_message);
            message_stats = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById (R.id.message_status);
            timestamp = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
            unreadbadge = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.unread);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext ()).inflate (R.layout.chat_list_style, parent, false);

        return new viewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(viewHolder holder, int position) {
        ChatroomLists chatroomLists =  ob1.get(position);
        Iterator<ChatroomLists> iter = ob1.iterator();
        String id = chatroomLists.getId();
        String time = chatroomLists.getTimestamp();



        Handler h = new Handler();
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("unread").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("chatrooms").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                try{
                    if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(id)){
                        holder.unreadbadge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }else {
                        holder.unreadbadge.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }
                }catch (Exception e){

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    long mtime = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(System.currentTimeMillis())-TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(Long.parseLong(time));
                    if (mtime<60){
                        holder.timestamp.setText(String.valueOf(mtime)+ " mins");
                        if (mtime==1)
                            holder.timestamp.setText(1+ " min");
                        else if (mtime<1){
                            holder.timestamp.setText("Just Now");

                        }
                        else
                            holder.timestamp.setText(mtime+ " mins");
                    }
                    else if (mtime>60 && mtime<1440){
                        if (mtime/60==1)
                            holder.timestamp.setText(String.valueOf(mtime/60)+ " hour");
                        else
                            holder.timestamp.setText(String.valueOf(mtime/60)+ " hours");
                    }
                    else if (mtime>=1440&&mtime<10080){
                        if (mtime/1440==1)
                            holder.timestamp.setText(String.valueOf(mtime/1440)+ " day");
                        else
                            holder.timestamp.setText(String.valueOf(mtime/1440)+ " days");
                    }else if(mtime>10080&&mtime<3679200){
                        if (mtime/10080==1)
                            holder.timestamp.setText(String.valueOf(mtime/10080)+ " week");
                        else
                            holder.timestamp.setText(String.valueOf(mtime/10080)+ " weeks");

                    }else if(mtime>3679200){
                        if (mtime/3679200==1)
                            holder.timestamp.setText(String.valueOf(mtime/3679200)+ " year");
                        else
                            holder.timestamp.setText(String.valueOf(mtime/3679200)+ " years");
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){

                }

                h.postDelayed(this,60000);
            }
        },60000);

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://droidchatz.firebaseio.com/groupchat/" + id + "/chat").limitToLast(1).addValueEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot d: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(d.getKey()).child("type").getValue(String.class).equals("text"))
                    holder.user_message.setText (dataSnapshot.child(d.getKey()).child("message").getValue(String.class));
                    else if(dataSnapshot.child(d.getKey()).child("type").getValue(String.class).equals("video"))
                        holder.user_message.setText ("New Video Message");

                    else if(dataSnapshot.child(d.getKey()).child("type").getValue(String.class).equals("image"))
                        holder.user_message.setText ("New Image Message");

                    else if(dataSnapshot.child(d.getKey()).child("type").getValue(String.class).equals("gif"))
                        holder.user_message.setText ("New GIF Message");

                    else if(dataSnapshot.child(d.getKey()).child("type").getValue(String.class).equals("file"))
                        holder.user_message.setText ("New Document");

                    else {
                        holder.user_message.setText (dataSnapshot.child(d.getKey()).child("message").getValue(String.class));

                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://droidchatz.firebaseio.com/groups/"+id+"/image").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                try{
                    Glide
                            .with(c)
                            .load(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class))
                            .asBitmap()
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)

                            .dontAnimate()
                            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {

                                @Override
                                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap arg0, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> arg1) {
                                    holder.user_img.setImageBitmap(arg0);
                                }});



                }catch (Exception e){

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        holder.user_name.setText (id);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (c, ChatRoom.class);
                intent.putExtra("username",username);
                intent.putExtra ("group_name", id);

                c.startActivity (intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return ob1.size();
    }


    }
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess - chnaging  'ob1.clear();' to 'this.ob1.clear();' will solve your problem,

Comment: Tried it  But still no success... @SanjeetAjnabee

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add values to your `ob1` object and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` to update your list.

Initialize your adapter only once and populate the `ob1` list.

Comment: I think that's what I am doing in the updatelist method

Comment: Not exactly. you are clearing the arraylist and populate it again. And that triggers a complete refresh. Just add or remove entries in your mainactivity (or where ever) to your list you handed over to your adapter and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged after that.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing your activity ArrayList reference into your adapter ArrayList reference:

```
  this.ob1 = ob1;
```

change in your adapter constructor, try it once:

```
 public ContactListAdapter(ArrayList<ChatroomLists> ob1, Context c, String fusername) {
    this.c = c;
    this.username = fusername;
    this.ob1.addAll(ob1);
}
```

Comment: when your are calling " if (!adapted) {
                chatLists.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapted = true;
            }else {
                adapter.updateList(ob1, getActivity(), fusername);

            }" ?

Comment: It's inside a firebase value event listener. So when the value changes it gets called.